# Including PHP constants

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to create a database config file that contains DB details, and then include the file in the files that I will be doing queries on, but I keep getting errors, it seems to be taking the constant as a string instead of it's value.

Here is the config.php code:

```
define("DB", "db", true);
define("LOGIN", "login", true);
define("PASS", "pass", true);
define("HOST", "server.com", true);
```

and here is where I include and use the constants:

```
include("config.php");

$province = $_POST['province'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$name_surname = $_POST['name_surname'];
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
$date = date("m.d.y");


$connect = mysql_connect(HOST,LOGIN,PASS) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (id, province, city, name_surname, email_address, date)
VALUES ('NULL', '$id', '$province', '$city', '$name_surname', '$email_address', '$date')", $connect) or die(mysql_error());
```

edit* Here is the error I am getting `Access denied for user 'USER'@'100-200-0-200.dynamic.adsl.com' (using password: YES)`

Any idea where I am going wrong? It's probably staring me in the face, but I just can't see it.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Can you post errors your getting.

Comment: I have edited my original post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without the specific error message generated it's hard to be certain, but I suspect the issue is simply that **the define is called "LOGIN", but you're attempting to use "USER"** in the mysql_connect call.

Comment: Whoops, in the PHP files they do correspond, jus a typo, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @user270311 If they corresponded, you wouldn't get getting the "Access denied for user 'USER'@..." error. Are you sure they're both in sync? (Unless the define contains the string "USER", this is what is happening.)

Comment: I am trying to do this for 3 different projects, and on the two files that I had open in the editor, they did correspond, only problem was that they were in two different directories of two different sites! SUCH an idiot mistake -_- thanx a million for the help guys! :)

Comment: @user270311 It happens to us all. (Once you've been bitten once, you'll double check next time anyway.) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try changing $connect = mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASS) by $connect = mysql_connect(HOST,LOGIN,PASS) as you don't define USER... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Constants.php
<?php

final class Constants 
{
    const DEBUG                     = true;

    const DB_CHARSET                = "latin1";
    const DB_PORT                   = 3306;
    const DB_TIMEOUT                = 15;
    const DB_HOST                   = "localhost";
    const DB_DATABASE               = "foo_db";
    const DB_USER                   = "foo_dbo";
    const DB_PASS                   = "pass";

    private function __construct(){}
}
?>

// usage:

require_once "Constants.php";

if(Constants::DEBUG){..}
```